# Can I pass a text file with all my parameters to maven?

Tags: maven

I've lot of arguments to pass to my build maven.
My command line is huge and change it is difficult ...
I don't want put arguments in the pom.xml so I want to know if I can create a text file where all my arguments'll be and pass it to the maven command:

mvn install -file

???
Thank you

Comment: The real question is: why do you have all those parameters? What problem are you having?

Comment: I pass lot of path to find sources, somes exe I use ...

Comment: Sounds wrong to me...show an example...usually a build should be running by `mvn clean install`  that should work...

Comment: I use cygwin to launch script .... i need paths to find sources ... i use izpack to launch installer ...